# Mainactivity statusbar color is white, can't change it

Tags: android-studio, android-statusbar

I've tried everything and i've not been able to the change the color of the statusbar. I have multiple activities that uses the same Style theme where I have declared the statusbar color as blue and it works. Mainactivity should also be using the same theme but its not. I've also tried changing the color by code which has not given any results.

**Android manifest:**

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logowbg"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/logowbg"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.MainActCustom">
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen" android:theme="@style/Apptheme.CustomSplash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ShowNewsDetailed" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".OptionsPop"
        android:theme="@style/Apptheme.CustomPopupStyle" />
    <activity android:name=".Settings" />
</application>
```

**MainActCustom:**

```
<style name="AppTheme.MainActCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/mainBGColor</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/mainBGColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/mainTextBGColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/mainBGColor</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if there ir2 styles files in your project. If there is, one is named "styles (v21)".

Check the line 
`<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>`